# How to control Tikz arrowhead size globally (in Beamer, if that matters)?

Tags: beamer, tikz-arrows

How do you globally set the default arrow size that Tikz uses when drawing graphical model diagrams?

Reduced example:

```latex
\documentclass[13pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,shapes,arrows,positioning,matrix,shapes.geometric,bayesnet}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \node[obs,circle] (a) {a};
    \node[obs,circle,right=of a] (b) {b};%
    \node[obs,circle,right=of b] (c) {c};%
    \edge {a} {b}; 
    \edge[style={-latex}] {b} {c};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- The code can't be littered with adjustments `[style={-latex}]` for every edge
- The adjustment should be a single command in the header that affects the default style for all arrows in all `tikzpicture`s
- I'd like to adjust the size somewhere between the default `->` and the smaller `-latex` (pictured above).

### Related questions

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150721/adjusting-the-size-of-an-arrow?rq=1) is very similar (the same?), but I couldn't pull a solution from the answers. The answers discuss how to override the style for single arrows, not how to scale all the default arrowheads by some fixed, global amount.

[This one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169061/tikz-increase-arrow-head-size) has an answer that is *way* too fancy for my needs, and it's hard for me to parse out what the simpler answer is from this larger amount of code.

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361652/changing-the-arrow-tip-size-in-tikz-cd) probably contains a hint for the answer, but it's for tikz-cd and sets the size of the "latex" arrow head, which isn't the default in Beamer it seems. Tex/Latex/Tikz/etc syntax is arcane enough that I can't guess what changes to this would let me set the default arrow size globally.

[This one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286442/how-to-change-color-and-transparency-of-arrows-in-tikz/286457#286457) changes some other arrow properties, but again---the langauge is such that one cannot guess a simplified command to affect the arrow head size.

[This one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/is-it-possible-to-change-the-size-of-an-arrowhead-in-tikz-pgf/161238#161238) probably contains the answer, but also contains a lot of extra information that is making it hard for me to parse out a simple solution to this specific issue.

From that question, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167031/28304) seems the simplest. I can confirm that adding

```latex
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{>={Latex[scale=1.2]}
```

Does seem to change the default arrow style to `Latex` and also configure its size.

Which raises the question: what was the default style in Beamer before applying this? Using `->` and `<->` by default draw a larger arrow than `-latex`, so it must be something else (in Beamer at least). What is it, and whats the simplest way to configure it?

Is there a way to scale whatever this default arrowhead is, or to *all* arrowheads? Such that using e.g. `\edge[style={<->}]` would automatically lead to an arrowhead of the desired size? It looks like this `arrows.meta` is a package for *very* fancy arrows, which I don't especially care about. Is there no way to globally adjust the size of the simpler/older arrows package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the arrow length: redefine the style `latent` from `bayesnet`. (`obs` is based on `latent`) Default uses  `node distance=1`.

Or use instead

```
    \tikzstyle{obs} = [circle,fill=white,draw=black,inner sep=1pt,
    minimum size=20pt, font=\fontsize{10}{10}\selectfont, node distance=0.5,fill=gray!25 ]
```

To avoid adding the optional parameter`[style={-latex}]` every time  to `\edge`, you can define a new command.

```
\newcommand{\edgex}[3][style={-latex}]{% edge with a new style <<<
    % Connect all nodes #2 to all nodes #3.
    \foreach \x in {#2} { %
        \foreach \y in {#3} { %
            \draw[#1] (\x) -- (\y) ;%
        } ;
    } ;
}
```

Putting everything together:

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[13pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,shapes,positioning,matrix,shapes.geometric,bayesnet}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\newcommand{\edgex}[3][style={-latex}]{% edge with a new style <<<
    % Connect all nodes #2 to all nodes #3.
    \foreach \x in {#2} { %
        \foreach \y in {#3} { %
            \draw[#1] (\x) -- (\y) ;%
        } ;
    } ;
}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \node[obs,circle] (a) {a};
    \node[obs,circle,right=of a] (b) {b};%
    \node[obs,circle,right=of b] (c) {c};%
    \edge {a} {b}; 
    \edge[style={-latex}] {b} {c};
\end{tikzpicture}
\bigskip
    
% change distance between nodes
\tikzstyle{obs} = [circle,fill=white,draw=black,inner sep=1pt,minimum size=20pt, font=\fontsize{10}{10}\selectfont, node distance=0.5,fill=gray!25 ]
    
    
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \node[obs,circle] (a) {a};
    \node[obs,circle,right=of a] (b) {b};%
    \node[obs,circle,right=of b] (c) {c};%
    \edge {a} {b}; 
    \edgex {b} {c};
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is the (global) setting `\tikzset{>={triangle 45}}` added by tikz library `bayesnet` that causes the size difference between arrows `->` and `-latex`. Nothing to do with class `beamer`.

According to the pgfmanual, sec. 16.4.4 Defining Shorthands, key handler `<key>/.tip`,

> By default, `>` is a shorthand for `To` and `To` is a shorthand for `to` (an arrow from the old libraries) when `arrows.meta` is not loaded library. When `arrows.meta` is loaded, `To` is redefined to mean the same as `Computer Modern Rightarrow`.

Hence you can use `\tikzset{<->/.tip=To}` to restore to the default arrow tip for `->`.

The size difference between arrow tips `triangle 45` and `latex` is built-in and can't be configured by arrow options like `scale`. Those arrow options are only supported by "complete" arrow tips defined in library `arrows.meta`, with their names with uppercase first letter. For example, `scale=1.2` works for `-{Latex[scale=1.2]}`, but is ignored for `-{latex[scale=1.2]}`.

Default arrow options can be set by

```tex
\tikzset{arrows={[<arrow options>]}}
```

see pgfmanual sec. 16.4.5 *"Scoping of Arrow Keys"*. but you must load `arrows.meta` and make sure all your arrow tips are "complete", aka aware of arrow options.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) {a};
  \node[right=of a] (b) {b};
  \node[right=of b] (c) {c};
  
  \path (a) edge[->] (b) 
        (b) edge[-Latex] (c);
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{arrows={[scale=3]}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) {a};
  \node[right=of a] (b) {b};
  \node[right=of b] (c) {c};
  
  \path (a) edge[->] (b) 
        (b) edge[-Latex] (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As a provisional answer, [this is almost the same question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/is-it-possible-to-change-the-size-of-an-arrowhead-in-tikz-pgf/167031#167031). Most of the answers are overkill for this application, but [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167031/28304) seems to result in scaling the default `->` and `<->` edges:

```latex
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{>={Latex[scale=1.2]}
```

It does leave some questions though: Is there a way to do this without using `arrows.meta`? It looks like `-latex`, `-Latex`, and `->`, all render with different sizes if `\tikzset{>={Latex[scale=1.2]` is removed. This tells me that the default arrow (in Beamer?) is not *exactly* `-latex` or `-Latex`? Is the default arrowhead one of `-latex` or `-Latex`, but perhaps scaled? If so, where is this set?

So I think these questions are still open:

- How is the default arrow(head) in Tikz configured?
- Can the user make global adjustments to it without using `arrows.meta`?
- Is there a generic "scale all arrowheads" command?
- Does Tikz behave slightly differently from within Beamer?

I'll accept any answer clarifying these ( :

Comment: Hi! Why don't you want to use `arrows.meta`? This replaces the old `arrows`, which is deprecated, and if it's deprecated, probably there are reasons (maybe this that you discovered is one of them!).